# Discordpy sending dms on var change but getting AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I’m trying to make a Discord bot that grabs the user_id from a variable and sends out information to those people only in private messages.
This is what I have tried.

```
#pulling the id from a variable
x = ''

@bot.command(name='add')
   async def add(ctx):
   global x
   x = ctx.message.author.id
   GAMESTATE = 2

@tasks.loop(seconds=10)
async def background():
    global GAMESTATE
    global x
    if GAMESTATE == 2:
        print('ssssss')
        user = bot.get_user(int(x))
        await user.send(message)
    else:
        pass
```

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'

Comment: Are you using intents?

Comment: I am not using intents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to let your bot retrieve a user object from the message context you need to give the bot the "members" intent like so (im assuming you already have messages intent turned on):

```
intents = discord.Intents(members=True, messages=True)
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)
```

however i would recommend in order to simplify thing to use:

```
intents = discord.Intents.all()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)
```

since most popular bots also require all intents (administrator rights).
most people wont mind and if you need to optimse/want less intents i recommend reading:
https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Intents
for more info